# How to rewrite deleting link_to helper to use it with glyphicon icon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glyphicons

I want my unattractive Delete link to become a glyphicon icon. How can I rewrite the following code?

```
   <%= link_to 'Delete', user_task_path(current_user, task.id),
        data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :method => :delete, remote: true %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
    <%= link_to user_task_path(current_user, task.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    <% end %>
```